# C++ interface design - IO board lowlevel protocol

Tags: c++, oop

I have a C++ class implementing the lowlevel interface (serial protocol) of a io board, the protocol has two commands to request board status (0x01 and 0x02) and returns, in the same answer, different values like temperature and io/status. The first command returns temperature1 and gpio 1 and 2, the second returns temperature2 and gpio 3 and 4. Ideally the consumer of this class won't known anything about internal implementation or board protocol, so I going to implement the lowlevel interface like

```
public:    
    int getTemperature1();
    bool getSwitch1();
    bool getSwitch2();

    int getTemperature2();
    bool getSwitch3();
    bool getSwitch4();
```

and the consumer will use it in this way:

```
board->getTemperature1(); //send command 0x01
board->getSwitch1();//send command 0x01

...

board->getTemperature2();//send command 0x02
board->getSwitch3();//send command 0x02
```

the problem I see is all this commands trigger the same commands on the serial interface, but I don't want this happen because it slows down the app and seems quite inefficient. My solution so far has been adding a method updateStatus1() and updateStatus2() in the lowlevel class and make the consumer call this method before reading any value:

```
board->updateStatus1();//send command 0x01
board->getTemperature1(); 
board->getSwitch1();

...
board->updateStatus2();//send command 0x02
board->getTemperature2();
board->getSwitch3();
```

Ofcourse the consumer must remember that before calling getTemperature1() and getSwitch1() has to call updateStatus1() and the same for updateStatus2(). In other words the consumer must be aware of internal implementation of lowlevel interface and if it doesn't remember to call updateStatus methods can read stale values without being aware of the mistake.

So I'm asking if anyone has come up with a better design to make the consumer less error prone and make the lowlevel class more efficient.

Comment: Implement some cache in the class, use a timer or something that will check if a call to `updateStatus1()` or 2 is needed inside the get methods.

Comment: You mean like associate a timestamp to each command updateStatus and then check it inside every get method, if the time from last read is greater than the maximum time allowed the value must be read again and timestamp updated. That's a good idea, thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could declare a `BoardStatus` structure, define a `GetBoardStatus` function returning this `BoardStatus` structure.

Inside the `GetBoardStatus` function you can incorporate all the logic and checks whether the actual board status has changed. If the actual board status has not changed you may return a cashed copy of it, if it has changed you will recalculate it before returning it.

This way to transfer all responsibility of updating the status in server side.

Comment: I don't like much the idea of returning a structure containing too many values since it would be difficult to known which values the client needs, in this way I would be forced to refresh everything using both commands 0x01 and 0x02. Anyway your approach is right, caching values is the way to go.

Comment: It all depends on two factors: 1) How many values this structure will hold and 2) How often you need to update its status. 
You may also keep a cashed copy of the status on the server side and read its properties.